# Adapt a tablet as a double din car stereo

Tags: honda, audio, diy

So this is the current Dash on my Honda Fit 2008:

[image: Dash kit]

I want to fit a Tablet (doesnt matter why but lets say costs and capabilities) and my main and only concern is for the device to charge when the car is turn to the I position (ACCESSORIES).

In order to do that i want to solder two cables from inside the cigarrette lighter in order to run the usb cable to the usb port of the tablet inside the panels and leave it there permanently (i dont want to plug an adapter to the cigarrette lighter port and hang a cable to the tablet).

I was thinking of soldering the two cables from the cigarrette lighter and use a device like this to get the 5 dcv needed:

> Pruveeo Hard Wire Kit for Dash Cam, Mini USB Port, 12V to 5V, DC 12V - 30V Car Charger Cable Kit
>   [image: Pruveeo Hard Wire Kit for Dash Cam, Mini USB Port, 12V to 5V, DC 12V - 30V Car Charger Cable Kit]

This in theory would work just as i expected, right? When i turn the key to the ACCESSORIES position the tablet should start to receive power and when the key is in the OFF position it should not drain any current from the battery.

Second: I bought my car used and as far as i can tell, it has an aftermarket radio (SONY) so it should already have an amplifier somewhere behind the dash, right?

To make things easier, i wanted to use the headphones jack in the tablet to output the sound to the amplifier that goes to the speakers throug RCA cables. Is this possible or I'm just wishing too much?

In case i have to fit an amplifier in there, how to get sound from headphones port to amplifier to speakers? Mainly the amplifier -> speakers is the main concern. I think i'll have to do some rewiring.

Answer (score 1):

So, for power supply, yes you can do that.

The existing sony may or may not have a separate amplifier, most probably the amp is built-in to the radio already which means you will have to source and fit one.

As for mounting, you will need to fabricate one - you may need to spend time in a shop looking at the versions they have available and seeing what you can re-make to work.

As an ex-vehicle electrician this is all possible electrically - the trick will be making it look neat and as if it is original...

An interesting project - good luck.